# How to prevent rollbar from reporting SEO crawlers activities?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rollbar

I have setup rollbar in my rails application. It keeps reporting recordnotfound which is as a result of SEO scrawlers (i.e Google bot, Baidu, findxbot etc..) searching for deleted post.

How to prevent rollbar from reporting SEO scrawler activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using [rollbar-gem](https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem), so you'd want to use `Rollbar::Ignore` to tell Rollbar to ignore errors that were caused by a spider

```
handler = proc do |options|
  raise Rollbar::Ignore if is_crawler_error(options)
end

Rollbar.configure do |config|
    config.before_process << handler
end
```

where `is_crawler_error` detects if the request that led to the error was from a crawler.

If you are using [rollbar.js](https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar.js) to detect errors in client-side Javascript, then you can use the `checkIgnore` option to filter out client-side errors caused by bots:

```
_rollbarConfig = {
  // current config...
  checkIgnore: function(isUncaught, args, payload) {
     if (window.navigator.userAgent && window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Baiduspider') !== -1) {
       // ignore baidu spider
       return true;
     }
     // no other ignores
     return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Where I can get more details on is_crawler_error method?

Comment: Hi Alif - Sorry for not being clear about this - You should define `is_crawler_error` (or any method to find spiders) yourself.  It should check the user agent value on the request against a list of known spiders that you want to block.

Comment: Came here in search for a recipe on how to implement the handler to ignore certain requests. Not sure how this can be an accepted answer if it's a complete copy-paste from the docs.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:**

```
# ./initializers/rollbar.rb
#
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36588449/how-to-prevent-rollbar-from-reporting-seo-crawlers-activities
# 
# frozen_string_literal: true

crawlers = %w[Facebot Twitterbot YandexBot bingbot AhrefsBot crawler MJ12bot Yahoo GoogleBot Mail.RU_Bot SemrushBot YandexMobileBot DotBot AppleMail SeznamBot Baiduspider]
regexp = Regexp.new(Regexp.union(*crawlers).source, Regexp::IGNORECASE)

Rollbar.configure do |config|
  ignore_bots = lambda do |options|
    agent = options.fetch(:scope).fetch(:request).call.fetch(:headers)['User-Agent']
    raise Rollbar::Ignore if agent.match?(regexp)
  end

  config.before_process << ignore_bots

  ...
end
```

**======================**

**Be careful with magic comment `frozen_string_literal` and use `=~` instead of `match?` if you have Ruby version less than 2.3.**

Here I use an array that will be transformed into regexp. I did this because I wanted to prevent syntax and escaping related errors of developers in future and add ignorecase thing for same reason.

So in regexp you will see a `Mail\.RU_Bot`, instead of anything wrong.

Also in your case you can use simply word `bot` instead of many crawlers, but be careful with unusual user-agents. In my case, I want to know all crawlers on my site, so I came up with this solution. Yet another example of working part: there are `crawler` and `crawler4j` on my production site. I use just `crawler` in array to prevent notifing for both of them.

Last thing I want to say — my solution *is not very optimal*, but it just works. I hope someone will share an optimized version of my code. That's also the main reason I recommend to send data *asynchronously*, i.e. use sidekiq, delayed_job or whatever you want, don't forget to check related wikis.

My answer is based on @AndrewSouthpaw's solution (?), that wasn't working for me. Hoping that approved *wiki-copy-pasted* @Jesse Gibbs will be moderated some way.

=======

EDIT1: it's nice idea to check the https://github.com/ZLevine/rollbar-ignore-crawler-errors repo if you need to prevent rollbar to notify on js.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
is_crawler_error = Proc.new do |options|
  return true if options[:scope][:request]['From'] == 'bingbot(at)microsoft.com'
  return true if options[:scope][:request]['From'] == 'googlebot(at)googlebot.com'
  return true if options[:scope][:request]['User-Agent'] =~ /Facebot Twitterbot/
end

handler = proc do |options|
  raise Rollbar::Ignore if is_crawler_error.call(options)
end

config.before_process << handler
```

Based on [these docs](https://rollbar.com/docs/notifier/rollbar-gem/#before-process-hook).